# Providing a column name for the resultant table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, alias

I have the below query to extract data in desired format

```
select
(
    select COUNT(serialNumber) as LOTQty
    from MobileData
    where mobileName = @mobileName and model = @model and LOTQty = @lotQty
)
,(
    select COUNT(serialNumber) as FailedQty
    from MobileData
    where mobileName = @mobileName and model = @model and LOTQty = @lotQty and PreScan = 'FAIL'
)
```

But when I execute the query it certainly gives the desired result but instead of column names **"LotQty"** and **"FailedQty"** it display **(No Column Name)** and **(No Column Name)**

I also tried modifying the above query as below but still the result remains same

```
select
(
    select [LotQty] = COUNT(serialNumber)
    ...
)
,(
    select [FailedQty] = COUNT(serialNumber) 
    ...
)
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give colmn name using **ALIAS** and also you can fetch both count using one query instead of two subqueries.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(serialNumber) AS LOTQty, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PreScan = 'FAIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FailedQty
FROM MobileData
WHERE mobileName = @mobileName AND model = @model AND LOTQty = @lotQty;
```

Comment: @Saharsh Shah thanks this approach is quite handy and performance effective. But as a newbie Im unable to understand the complexities of it. Would you care to explain it to me please?
What if I have multiple conditions like preScan, midScan and postScan then how would I build my query?

Comment: Ok and what if I want 3 conditions like preScan, midScan and postScan? I go ahead with two more lines like
Sum(CASE WHEN MidScan = 'FAIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FailedmidQty
Sum(CASE WHEN PostScan = 'FAIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FailedPostQty

Answer (score 2):

The alias name must be outside the subquery

```
select
(
    select COUNT(serialNumber) 
    from MobileData
    where mobileName = @mobileName and model = @model and LOTQty = @lotQty
) as LOTQty
,(
    select COUNT(serialNumber)
    from MobileData
    where mobileName = @mobileName and model = @model and LOTQty = @lotQty and PreScan = 'FAIL'
)  as FailedQty
```

Comment: How possibly could I miss such a small thing? Anyways thanks a buck for saving my day :)

Comment: One question arising here. Now when I want to access that data in my code can I directly access it using the column name "LotQty" and "FailedQty"?